# pep 420 namespace_packages purpose in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

What is the purpose of the **namespace_packages** argument in setup.py when working with PEP420 namespace packages (the ones without __init__.py)?

I played with it and saw **no difference** whether I declared the namespace packages or not.
"setup.py install" and "pip install ." worked in any case.

I am building an automatic setup.py code generator and would be happy not to handle this if this is not necessary.

Comment: I would suggest to switch to `pyproject.toml` as `setup.py` is an obsolete solution: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you:

- aim for Python 3.3 and newer or Python 2.7 with `importlib2` dependency installed (a backport of `importlib` for Python 2),
- use a recent version of `setuptools` for packaging (I think it should be 28.8 or newer)
- and use a recent `pip` version for installing (9.0 and newer will be fine, 8.1.2 will probably also work, but you should test that yourself),

you are on the safe side and can safely omit the `namespace_packages` keyword arg in your setup scripts.

There is a [PyPA's official repository named `sample-namespace-packages` on GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages) that contains a suite of tests for different possible scenarios of distributions installed that contain namespace packages of each kind. As you can see, the sample packages using the implicit namespace packages don't use `namespace_packages` arg in their setup scripts (here is [one of the scripts](https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages/blob/master/native/pkg_a/setup.py)) and all of the tests of types `pep420` and `cross_pep420_pkgutil` pass on Python 3; here is [the complete results table](https://github.com/pypa/sample-namespace-packages/blob/master/table.md).

Answer (score 0):

Namespace packages are *separate* packages that are installed under one top-level name.

Usually two different packages (for example [SQLObject](https://pypi.org/project/SQLObject/) and [Cheetah3](https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/)) install two (or more) different top-level packages (`sqlobject` and `Cheetah` in my examples).

But what if I have a library that I want to split into parts and allow to install these parts without the rest of the library? I use namespace packages. Example: these two packages are 2 parts of one library: [m_lib](https://pypi.org/project/m-lib/) and  [m_lib.defenc](https://pypi.org/project/m-lib.defenc/). One installs `m_lib/defenc.py` which can be used separately, the other installs the rest of the `m_lib` library. To install the entire library at once I also provide [m_lib.full](https://pypi.org/project/m-lib.full/).

PS. All mentioned packages are mine. Source code is provided at [Github](https://github.com/phdru) or [my personal git hosting](https://git.phdru.name/).

Comment: This doesn't say anything about the `namespace_packages` argument in `setup.py`.

Comment: All 3 `m_lib` packages use `namespace_packages = ["m_lib"]` in `setup.py` because `m_lib` is the top-level package name for all parts of the library.

Comment: But what will happen if you don’t declare namespace_packages=[“m_lib”]?

Comment: Second installation (`pip install m_lib`) will override the first (`pip install m_lib.defenc`) instead of adding a part of the library.