# PyPI pip install submodules

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi

I read the [Packing Projects Documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), searched this question here in stackoverflow but found nothing similar, and my low experience using third-party library tells me it's not possible.
The closest I got was [pip install from git repo branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch)

Let's suppose I have two python libraries in PyPI, each one with it's own repository and I can install them using the `pip`:

```
pip install mylib-foo
pip install mylib-bar
```

currently I can import them using

```py
import mylibfoo
import mylibbar
```

**Question 1**: Is there a way to import them using the code below, without merging the repositories and create only one PyPI project?

```
import mylib.foo
import mylib.bar
```

Merging the repositories I mean just like `numpy` does: We can import `numpy.linalg` and `numpy.random`, but they both are in the same repository/project.

**Question 2**: Now let's suppose that we have only one PyPI project, in only one repository (just like `numpy` does). Is there a way to install only a part of the `mylib` library?

```
pip install mylib-foo  # Install only mylib.foo
pip install mylib-bar  # Install only mylib.bar
pip install mylib  # Install both
```

So, if someone did only `pip install mylib-foo` and tries to import `mylib.bar`, he receives an error.

Comment: You're looking for [Namespace packages](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html). See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+namespace+packages Also see my examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282888/7976758

Comment: You could also create a folder called *mylib* with an __init__.py. Inside the init, you can import the modules as so: ```import mylibfoo as foo \n import mylibbar as bar```. Now when you write ```import mylib.foo```, *mylib* is referring to the directory you created. For enforcing different modules to be installed as a bundle, I would look into using the tool [pipenv](https://docs.pipenv.org/).