# What is the best practice for releasing python packages with a base version and a full version?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I'm developing a Python package where I wish to have a 'base' version and a 'full' version. The base version will have the bare bones stuff whereas the 'full' version will have extra functionality. My package structure looks something like this:

```
my_package/
  pyproject.toml
  src/
    base/
      __init__.py
      module1.py
    full/
      __init__.py
      module2.py
```

I was hoping I could use extras to handle this but I can't figure out how to conditionally include modules conditioned on extras, i.e. `pip install my_package` vs. `pip install my_package[full]`.

Comment: Namespace packages. See the description of my [`m_lib` library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282888/7976758). It has 3 variants, one of which is full.